# how to count element inside lists of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```
allName = {
          'name1': ['sainz', 'gasly'], 
          'name2': ['sainz', 'gasly', 'stroll'],
          'name3': ['sainz', 'gasly', 'stroll']
}
```

How can I know that there are 3 `sainz` names, 3 'gasly' names, 2 'stroll' names inside the dictionary?

I want to print it out like this:

```
sainz: 3
gasly: 3
stroll: 2
```

Thanks before hand!

Comment: What have you done to achieve the same?

Comment: Check out collections.counter https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way would probably collections counter plus itertools.chain

```
import itertools    
import collections
print(collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*data.values()))
```

I think would work

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

allName = {
          'name1': ['sainz', 'gasly'], 
          'name2': ['sainz', 'gasly', 'stroll'],
          'name3': ['sainz', 'gasly', 'stroll']
}

res = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in allName.items():
    for i in v:
        res[i]+=1
        
for k, v in res.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

**Output:**

```
sainz: 3
gasly: 3
stroll: 2
```

Comment: Thanks you! but look like the above answer is the shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is using Counter from collections

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for names in allName.values():
...     for name in names:
...             c[name] += 1
...
>>> c
Counter({'sainz': 3, 'gasly': 3, 'stroll': 2})
>>>
```

**explanation** :
loops : Iterate through the dictionary and find all the items in the lists.
count : Then add them to counter.